# cordova add platforms android command failed

Tags: android, apache, cordova

I get a really strange problem when I type
    cordova platforms add android
After I've pressed [Enter], I get the following error:

```
[Error: The command 'android' failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the 'android' command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path. Output: ]
```

But, I've correctly setup my PATH and the proof of that is that when I type android command or java or ant or adb, it's working but not for Cordova apparently.

Could you please help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I also came across the same problem while adding android platform for cordova through command prompt.

It is very simple open **Android SDK Manager**

**and install the latest version on Android SDK platform(4.2.2)**

[image]

As you can see the latest sdk platform version i.e 4.2.2 is installed.
So do the same and should solve your problem.

**Now try again to run the command to add platform android for cordova.**

> add platform android

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, even after restarted my computer, the same error is still appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project.properties and AndroidManifest file for the API level of Android SDK against your installed Android SDK.

Steps:

- Find your android sdk details in `source.properties` file(`{android sdk}/platforms/Android-x.x/`). Basically find the `AndroidVersion.ApiLevel`
- Edit your `project.propereties` file(`{Project_name}/platforms/android/`) and change `target=android-xx` acoording to `AndroidVersion.ApiLevel`
- Edit your `AndroidManifest` file (`{Project_name}/platforms/android/`) and change `android:targetSdkVersion="xx"` accordingly.

Hopefully it will work.